# In UWP, 'getHostEnvironmentValue' giving an exception by invoking via JavaScript

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

In My UWP project, I am using a Javascript to get the os-sku value,

**MainWindows.xaml.cs:**

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //Load local html file using 'Navigate' method    
            WebBrowserName.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///HTMLPage1.html"));
            }

        async void WebBrowserName_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Value.StartsWith("SomeValue"))
            {
                Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Calling javascript function from C#");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();   
            }
        }

        private  void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                        WebBrowserName.InvokeScriptAsync("JSMethod", new string[] { "" });
        }

    }
```

**and HTMLPage1.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javaScript">
        function JSMethod() {
           external.getHostEnvironmentValue('os-sku'); //Exception Occured
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    "OSSKU :
    <p id="demo">
        <script></script>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

After deploying the UWP app and while running the above app, I am getting an,
**Exception** :

> UWP 0x800a01b6 - javascript runtime error: object doesn't support
>   property or method 'gethostenvironmentvalue'

I am not able to figure it out, what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As the [getHostEnvironmentValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mt795399(v=vs.100)#MainContent) method introduction, this method is only available in Microsoft Edge. Even througn web view control embeds a view into your uwp app that renders web content using the Microsoft Edge rendering engine, but the UWP [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) is different from the Edge, moreover, the UWP apps run sandboxed, it has more security and resource access limitations. So, as the exception, this [getHostEnvironmentValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mt795399(v=vs.100)#MainContent) method can not be used in UWP app, it is not supported.